# Recombine capture groups in single regexp?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to handle input groups similar to:

`'...A.B.'` and want to output `'.....AB'`.

Another example:

`'.C..Z..B.' ==> '......CZB'`

I have been working with the following:

```
'...A.B.'.replace(/(\.*)([A-Z]*)/g, "$1")
```

returns:

```
"....."
```

and

```
'...A.B.'.replace(/(\.*)([A-Z]*)/g, "$2")
```

returns:

```
"AB"
```

but

```
'...A.B.'.replace(/(\.*)([A-Z]*)/g, "$1$2")
```

returns

```
"...A.B."
```

Is there a way to return

```
"....AB"
```

with a single regexp?

I have only been able to accomplish this with:

```
'...A.B.'.replace(/(\.*)([A-Z]*)/g, "$1") + '...A.B.'.replace(/(\.*)([A-Z]*)/g, "$2")
```

==> `".....AB"`

Comment: Do you need to handle the input `...A..B...C.` => `.........ABC`? Always tells us **in words** what the regex is supposed to do, as well as with examples.

Comment: edited question to clarify. hmm... in the javascript engine in chrome 59.0, it returns the expected output: `'...A.B.'.replace(/(\.*)([A-Z]*)/g, "$1") + '...A.B.'.replace(/(\.*)([A-Z]*)/g, "$2")
// ===>  ".....AB"`

Comment: The input string has 5 dots, one is after the final 'B'. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Not your fault, mine. :-) At least three times I failed to count the one *between* `A` and `B`.

Comment: FWIW, I've clarified my answer a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the goal is to move all of the `.` to the beginning and all of the `A-Z` to the end, then I believe the answer to

> with a single regexp?

is "no."

Separately, I don't think there's a simpler, more efficient way than two `replace` calls — but not the two you've shown. Instead:

```js
var str = "...A..B...C.";
var result = str.replace(/[A-Z]/g, "") + str.replace(/\./g, "");
console.log(result);
```

(I don't know what you want to do with non-`.`, non-`A-Z` characters, so I've ignored them.)

If you *really* want to do it with a single call to `replace` (e.g., a single pass through the string matters), you can, but I'm fairly sure you'd have to use the function callback and state variables:

```js
var str = "...A..B...C.";
var dots = "";
var nondots = "";
var result = str.replace(/\.|[A-Z]|$/g, function(m) {
  if (!m) {
    // Matched the end of input; return the
    // strings we've been building up
    return dots + nondots;
  }
  // Matched a dot or letter, add to relevant
  // string and return nothing
  if (m === ".") {
    dots += m;
  } else {
    nondots += m;
  }
  return "";
});
console.log(result);
```

That is, of course, incredibly ugly. :-)

Comment: I like the simplicity of `var result = str.replace(/[A-Z]/g, "") + str.replace(/\./g, "");` , rather than using the capture groups. Thanks.

Comment: @LexJacobs: Yeah. It's only two passes through the string, not that bad. :-)